# How do i get the text of a UI element to move in Unity 4.6+?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

When the player approaches an item I want some of it's properties to be displayed, but I don't want that info to cover up the player.  I have the following code which does not work.

```
t = GetComponentInChildren<Text> ();

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col){
    if (col.gameObject.tag.Equals ("Player")) {
        playerInRange = true;
        col.GetComponent<Controller>().itemsInRange.Add(this.gameObject);
        GetComponentInChildren<Canvas> ().enabled = true;
    }
    if (player.transform.position.x < this.transform.position.x) {
        Debug.Log ("On yer right!");
        t.rectTransform.position.Set(this.transform.position.x+50,  this.transform.position.z, this.transform.position.z);
    }
    if (player.transform.position.x > this.transform.position.x) {
        t.rectTransform.position.Set(this.transform.position.x-50,  this.transform.position.z, this.transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

The Debug.Log shows up, so all conditions are being met, but the text is not moving.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the getter for `tranform.position` returns a 'copy' of the position Vector3, so calling Set will only change the 'copy' of that vector3 and not the position of the rect transform.

This is because Vector3 is a struct and not a class and therefore isnt passed via reference. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx

so instead of calling set i would assign a new vector 3 to the position variable

`t.rectTransform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x-50, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);`

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're hitting the debug, can you verify the position you are displaying is where you expect it to be, currently the second and third parameters to the 'Set' method is:

```
 this.transform.position.z
```

Wouldn't the middle one be expected to be position.y?

Comment: One of the the.transform.position.z should be y, but that isn't causing this problem.  None of the position fields are changing.